# How to override fotorama.js Magento ver. 2.2.5

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Is there a way to remove the product name below the product image on the product detail page?

How to override fotorama.js?

Thanks,
JM

Answer (score 1):

Try to put it it in your custom theme at below path.

```
app/design/frontend/YourThemeVendor/Theme/web/fotorama/fotorama.js
```

Deploy static content and clear cache to see changes.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I already tried that one and still not working.

Comment: I tried its working for me. Try to remove first `fotorama.js` from pub folder than deploy static content. Let me know if it works.

Comment: If it works than give up vote and accept answer to help other community members.

Answer (score 1):

Create requirejs-config.js file in your module - Path should be like Vendor/ModuleName/frontend/requirejs-config.js

Code to be placed with in requirejs-config.js file:

If fotorama.js exists in Core/Vendor

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Review/js/process-reviews':'Vendor_ModuleName/js/fotorama.js'
        }
    }
};
```

If fotorama.js is not existed in Vendor(Place your script inside Vendor/ModuleName/frontend/web/js/fotorama.js)

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            uniqueName:'Vendor_ModuleName/js/fotorama'            
        }
    }
};
```